# Is it possible to make sense of reality that is independent 'our understanding'

Tags: philosophy-of-science, kant, hume

Kant has a famous quote;

> Thoughts without content are empty, intuitions without concepts are blind

This suggests we can't understand anything without (independently of) the use of concepts, which are human and mental things. But evolution through natural selection seems to suppose a world that existed before our understanding and is independent of our concepts. Is this possible?

Comment: The idea that concepts are (exclusively) human things is a vast assumption. It would make a mockery of Kant. One has to think in terms of 'mind-in-general'.

Comment: I see two problems in trying to answer the question.  What "reality" do you have in mind?  Personal, scientific, mathematical, religious, logical, etc.?  Before we can make sense of it, we must know (or agree on a definition of) what reality IS!

Comment: Just to add the cite.Critique of Pure Reason: “thoughts without content are empty, intuitions without concepts are blind” (A51/B76).

Comment: I don't think the question does necessarily involve the mind body problem or dualism. Even if the mind is a separate substance from the physical universe it may or may not be possible for it to make sense of a reality that is independent of our understanding. You need to concentrate on the question, not on the mind body problem, or dualism.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which "reality" you have in mind:

There is **physical** reality - independent of humans and their understandings.

There is **personal** reality - each human has their own "reflection" of reality inside their brain/consciousness.

There is **religious** reality - includes personal reality, deities, and intangible places.

In addition, we must come to an agreement on what **we mean** by "reality."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible; by trying to see how the contents of a situation can THEMSELVES be sufficient to bring about what occurs, or what we are trying to understand. This does not PROVE that what we come up with is independent of our understanding, but in as far as we seem successful there is no evidence it does depend on our understanding.

An example of this is evolution through natural selection, which in turn was influenced by uniformitarianism; the view that the natural world should be explained by the continuation of objects properties and processes currently observable. It is by the continuation of these things that the contents of a situation can seem themselves sufficient.

This in turn gives a different answer to Hume's questions why we suppose the continued (and independent) existence of body; Because, if we can suppose the continued existence of some object as a situation develops, we don't have to draw a conclusion beyond its original existence, so the continuation of that objects original existence must appear sufficient for its part in the development of the situation. For example, if we suppose an object that travels to disappear behind a screen and then re-appears on the other side of the screen; if we can suppose it is the same existence that continues and re-appears, since we don't have to draw a conclusion beyond that original existence, it appears sufficient to account for the subsequent appearance. But if that original existence is to account in this way for the subsequent appearances it must exist behind the screen even in those parts we haven't imagined or thought of.

In this way cause and effect can be made objective sense of insofar as we can avoid drawing conclusions beyond factors in a situation, making the situation a re-arrangement. So, instead of Hume's example of the collision of two billiard balls, we can take an example similar to Archimedes's thinking, that of a ball being pushed into a bucket of water. Since the volume of ball and water continue, as do their other properties (known by experience) such as impermeability of the ball, and fluidity of and weight of the water; as the ball is pushed into the water volume of ball-plus water is more than volume of water alone so the water level rises (and I believe you can see why, if these things continue together in the situation that result should be necessary; no other result is compatible with their continued existence together in the situation). The effect is a re-arrangement, not something essentially new.

Since we are trying to avoid drawing conclusions beyond 'objects' this is different from having to add any description to the situation. So, again, what we are up to is not something obviously added to the situation by us.  But of course, it is not the only possible way/attitude towards handing the situation.

Comment: "In as far as we seem successful there is no evidence it does depend on our understanding"??? The usual position is that what we know *obviously* depends on our concepts, the idea then is to figure out some weaker sense of "independent" that might still apply. Unfortunately I do not see anything in that direction in what you say. "Avoid drawing conclusions beyond factors in a situation" does not help, already the "factors", or the "situation" for that matter, are human concepts that can not be "objective" in an unrestricted sense.

Comment: what do you make of the argument that the world of evolution through natural selection can't essentially depend on anything human because for most of the time it operated there were no humans, or their minds, or language or concepts, and these are all accidental products of it?--we might have to employ some of these things in order to realise its true, but what we realise is true can't depend on them.

Comment: "The world of evolution", "minds", "accidents", etc., are all human concepts themselves, and what we realize as true depends on their meaning, hence is itself laced with our understanding. To get an argument you can not operate with the naive unanalyzed concept of "independent", and even more sophisticated attempts to do so by various philosophers are controversial.

Comment: So according to you we have a concept of a world, and a concept of evolution through natural selection, and a concept of being accidental, and a concept of existing for hundreds of millions of years. But although in combining these concepts we get the perhaps true concept that humans and their concepts didn’t exist for hundreds of millions of years and it is just luck if they ever do exist, we are unable to make sense of this ‘existing for hundreds of millions of years independently of concepts’ because that’s just our concept?

Comment: Or perhaps you think that we can make some sense of a world independently of our concepts, but it will be inevitably tainted by our concepts? But how is there something we can see is tainted by our concepts unless we can get some sort of inkling of it independently of our concepts? If everything is conceptual, there isn’t anything left to be tainted.

Comment: Doesn’t Kant’s quote strike you as odd?
“Thoughts without content are empty”….Empty thoughts are (surprise) empty.
“intuitions without concepts are blind”
But if intuitions on their own are blind what can we know of them? How can you make sense of something that can’t be made sense of unless you add a concept to ‘it’? ‘IT@ is in danger of completely disappearing.

Comment: You are trying to see it in two ways, one through the (tainted) glass of our concepts, and the other ideally, and then to hypothetically compare the two. The problem is with this approach rather than with independence or truth. We can not step out of ourselves and compare what we have to what is out there "independently", not even hypothetically, it is self-contradictory. What we actually mean by independence is something else, that we do not get to choose our descriptions at whim, that reality "pushes back" on them, not that concepts in them are untainted by us.

Comment: Concepts do apply retroactively, evolution theory is of course true (or at least highly likely), and we can make sense of it, just not in the incoherent way of pretending to "compare" something ours to something "in itself" which nonetheless is imagined to be ours enough for comparison to make sense. This "it" to which something ours is added is a just confused notion. As for Kant, his quote is not about this. Both intuitions and concepts are our productions for him, concrete and abstract respectively. Abstractions on their own are empty, concretions on their own are blind.

Comment: I don’t think I’m the one saying we have to get outside our perspective in order to make sense our understanding of a situation apparently not depending on us and ‘our understanding’. You are the one maintaining for our understanding of a situation apparently not to depend on us and ‘our understanding’ we’d have to use ‘our concepts’ and try to get outside the perspective of ‘our understanding’. And I, in my last posts was taking the rise out of your position.

Comment: What I am saying is, if we can see how a situation and the objects in it seem THEMSELVES SUFFICIENT to bring about what occurs in the situation, as seems to be the case with evolution through natural selection, then our understanding of the situation, apparently, does not depend on ‘our understanding’ because they couldn’t appear THEMSELVES SUFFICIENT if it did.

Comment: So do you think the theory of evolution through natural selection shows how the natural world is itself sufficient to produce the evolution of life forms up to the presently observable states? Isn’t this how it does away with the need for a designer god, because, since the natural world is itself sufficient there is nothing left for a designer god to do? (but also, variations appear random, and weeded out by survival and reproducing pressures so this seems inconsistent with a god choosing which variations will occur, and which if they occur will survive.)

Comment: "if we can see how a situation and the objects in it seem themselves sufficient to bring about what occurs in the situation... then our understanding of the situation, apparently, does not depend on ‘our understanding’" sounds incoherent to me. If it "seems" that way (it doesn't to me) perhaps we are not looking closely enough, at the situation, and especially at ourselves. Many myths "explain" their own creation too, that does not make them independent of their creators, so this sort of argument can not work. I am also not sure why god is relevant here.

Comment: You think that our understanding is something we do and obviously depends on our perspective, concepts and ideas, and we can't get outside them to check if what we are upto is true independently of our perspective ideas and concepts. But consider the situation if our understanding consists in attempts to see how the contents of situations can themselves bring about what happens. If we succeed so that we seem to show how the contents themselves are sufficient to bring about what occurs what is the reason for still maintaining this must depend on us?

Comment: As before, the problem is with the unanalyzed sense of "depend". There is a sense in which reality is independent of us, and there is a sense in which our descriptions of it are so dependent. Contents of descriptions are certainly not sufficient to bring about anything by themselves, so one implicitly substitutes their real referents for them. That is fair enough in many contexts. But such substitution projects onto reality things of our own creation. A natural move then is to try "separating" them from the "truly real", but it only leads to another projection, and often incoherence.

Comment: “But such substitution projects onto reality things of our own creation”
But what evidence do you have for saying they are ‘of our own creation’ if what we are up to is trying to see how things are themselves sufficient to bring about what occurs? It seems to me your problem is, basically, that you think our understanding must be based on the properties of our descriptions, but descriptions don’t bring anything about, so ‘in many cases’ its fair enough to try and substitute the things themselves,

Comment: There are two problems 1)how do we exclude other possible points of view? 2) you are still nagged by the thought that we must look to the properties of our descriptions to explain how we understand a ‘real’ situation.

 2)Take my ball being pushed into a bucket of water example; we could try to deduce logically from the properties of the words applicable to it what will happen, or alternatively we can just compare the objects and properties as they pass in the situation, and by making these comparisons see if their continued existence is sufficient to bring about the rise in the water level.

Comment: This understanding does not depend on the properties of the language applied to the situation but on noticing how we don’t need to go beyond the factors noticeable in the situation to get the result. So we haven’t added anything to the situation, we’ve just noticed how the factors we find in it appear themselves sufficient to bring about the rise in water level, if they continue, which they seem to do. But 1) what restricts us is we are not trying to add something to the situation, but trying to avoid going beyond factors we can notice in the situation.

Comment: You are still caught up in the same circle as before, so let me end with advice. You should look at modern versions of realism and how they treat reality, our relation to reality and independence. The more naive notions you are using have been extensively analyzed by philosophers, and in their terms your pursuit is unpromising.

Comment: So you think that pointing out that insofar as something appears itself sufficient to produce something this is logically incompatible with it appearing dependent on something else is not giving an analysis of 'dependent', or if something appears to 'depend' on something else?

Comment: @JustinLeSaux Let me get this straight, you are saying that you can look at a "situation" and understand what is happing without prior knowledge of any concepts to facilitate such understandings? I could believe that _if_ you can describe to me such an instance, i.e. describe a concept that noone has heard before without using  composites of known concepts

Answer (score 0):

" Let me get this straight, you are saying that you can look at a "situation" and understand what is happing without prior knowledge of any concepts to facilitate such understandings? I could believe that if you can describe to me such an instance, i.e. describe a concept that noone has heard before without using composites of known concepts – christo183 2 "

The thing is why you say something is conceptual? Because someone's heard of it before? Or perhaps because there are alternative ways of handling 'reality'? I don't think either of these require it must be conceptual. If a ball being pushed into a bucket of water makes the water level rise because the volume of the ball + water is greater than the water volume alone, so the water must go somewhere else, so it rises in the bucket. This shows how the ball being pushed into the water is sufficient for the effect, but if it needed to depend on our concepts the ball and the water could themselves be sufficient.